# Python Script to route openstreetmaps

Tags: python, json, maps

I created a python script to get the distances between two coordinates taken from a json file into OSRM. Any coordinate gives me 0 as a result...
I also tried to manually enter the data on the site http://router.project-osrm.org and it doesn't seem to work there either

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

example:
http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/45.65419,13.787336;45.647353,13.779722

result:

```
{
   "code":"Ok",
   "routes":[
      {
         "geometry":"axesAe{bvG??",
         "legs":[
            {
               "steps":[
                  
               ],
               "summary":"",
               "weight":0,
               "duration":0,
               "distance":0
            }
         ],
         "weight_name":"routability",
         "weight":0,
         "duration":0,
         "distance":0
      }
   ],
   "waypoints":[
      {
         "hint":"dE3NhJFNzYRMAAAAAAAAAJUUAAAAAAAAWvunQgAAAAC_zbZFAAAAAEwAAAAAAAAAlRQAAAAAAADeGgAAnM25AqWH0gCuoLgCyGDSAJMAbxOcVasg",
         "distance":8403.160528419,
         "name":"",
         "location":[
            45.731228,
            13.797285
         ]
      },
      {
         "hint":"dE3NhJFNzYRMAAAAAAAAAJUUAAAAAAAAWvunQgAAAAC_zbZFAAAAAEwAAAAAAAAAlRQAAAAAAADeGgAAnM25AqWH0gD5hbgCCkPSAJMAbxOcVasg",
         "distance":9275.904005220,
         "name":"",
         "location":[
            45.731228,
            13.797285
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Latitude and longitude must be reversed

Wrong:
http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/45.65419,13.787336;45.647353,13.779722

Right:
http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.787336,45.65419;13.779722,45.647353